# cookie is not set in browser regardless setting everything

Tags: node.js, angular, cookies, cors, http-headers

there are several questions in this topic. I tried many of the proposed solutions, but still I can't get it work.

I have a backend (NestJs) on localhost:3000 and a frontend (Angular) on localhost:4200.

On the backend I have this settings for cookies:

```
MAX_AGE_ACCESS_TOKEN=432000000 # 5 days
MAX_AGE_REFRESH_TOKEN=1728000000 # 20 days
HTTP_ONLY=false
SECURE=false
SAME_SITE='none'
```

These are actual basic settings, allowing everything, since I was experimenting, what is wrong.

I have also enabled CORS, set `credentials` to true, exposed the `Set-Cookie` header, etc:

```
app.enableCors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
    allowedHeaders: [
      'Origin',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
      'Content-Type',
      'Accept',
      'Jwt-Token',
      'Authorization',
      'Origin',
      'Accept',
      'X-Requested-With',
      'Access-Control-Request-Method',
      'Access-Control-Request-Headers',
    ],
    exposedHeaders: [
      'Origin',
      'Content-Type',
      'Accept',
      'Jwt-Token',
      'Authorization',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',
      'Set-Cookie',
    ],
    credentials: true,
  });
```

If I do a log in, I see in the dev tools (chrome), that the response has the `Set-Cookie` header with the two tokens (access and refresh). However under the tab 'application' there is no cookies set.

On the frontend I make f. e. a logout request setting `withCredentials` to true:

```
logout() {
    return this.http.get(`${API_URL}/auth/logout`, { withCredentials: true });
  }
```

but I get an unauthorized error, since there is no cookies stored in the browser on localhost:4200  and Angular can't get this.

What is going on here? What am I missing?

Comment: Modern versions of Chrome won't let you set an insecure cookie (i.e. a cookie not marked `Secure`) with `SameSite=None`; see https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2020/01/get-ready-for-new-samesitenone-secure

Comment: I forget to use `withCredentials` also in the login method. Now, everything is fine.